# Blogroll/Lins Menu not visible in my backend?

Tags: links, blogroll

well, i'm confused. I can't seem to find out why my "Links" Menu doesn't show up in my wordpress admin.

I have this in my `functions.php` file …

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_links_menu' );

function remove_links_menu() {
    remove_menu_page('themes.php'); // Appearance
    remove_menu_page('tools.php'); // Tools
    //remove_menu_page('link-manager.php'); // Links
    //remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php'); // Comments
}
```

However it clearly says, that `link-manager.php` is not removed. If comment-out the entire action the `themes` and `tools` Menus are showing back up. However the link-manager is never visible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Links_Manager): "As of [Version 3.5](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.5), the Links Manger and blogroll are hidden for new installs and any existing WordPress installs that do not have any links. If you are upgrading from a previous version of WordPress with any active links, the Links Manager will continue to function as normal. If you would like to restore the Links panel to your install you may download and install the [Links Manager plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/link-manager/)."